.Net Core Fluent Validation - Calling inner async validator
I was reading this question about calling an inner validator inside of a custom validator, and I noticed that in the [documentation for Asynchronous Validation] (https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/async.html) it says:

If your validator contains asynchronous validators or asynchronous conditions, it’s important that you always call ValidateAsync on your validator and never Validate. If you call Validate, then an exception will be thrown.

In my case, my inner validator performs asynchronous validation, and I tried to see if I could change the answer that worked in the previous stack overflow post to use an async validator instead:
  RuleForEach(c => c.Address)
           .SetAsyncValidator(new AsyncAddressValidator());

However, this gave me an error that SetAsyncValidator expects a parameter of type IAsyncPropertyValidator<ParentModel, ChildModel>, which I could not find anywhere in the documentation, and seemed not to be what I was looking for, as the async validator for my child type does not care who its parents are.
So, I was wondering, how do I do this in an elegant way? And furthermore, is there another class similar to IValidator<T> that allows me to define a validator that is specifically async?
In my project the classes receive the validator via dependency injection as IValidator<T>, so I do not know from the IValidator<T> type whether it's an async validator or not:
public MyParentValidator(IValidator<ChildType> childValidator)
{
    this.RuleForEach(x => x.children).SetValidator(childValidator); // Impossible to know whether childValidator is async
}

And since ValidateAsync calls the synchronous rules anyway, it seems to me like I should always call the async variant just to be safe.
Is there an elegant way to go about this? because the documentation does not specify anything more and I'm a bit at a loss.

Update: after learning a little more about how rules are declared, I assume that SetValidator will add the async rules as async, and that SetAsyncValidator is something completely unrelated.
